# Pytorch newbie, non linear regression not converging

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

First im new to pytorh and DL, I want to create a simple non linear regression model, but apparently is not converging, i tried to change some hyperparams without sucess. This is the code, i guess im making wrong something obvius.

```
    import torch
    
    x1 = torch.arange(1,600,1,  dtype=torch.float32).view(-1,1)
    y1 = x1*x1
    
    model = torch.nn.Sequential(
        torch.nn.Linear(1,500),
        torch.nn.ReLU(),
        torch.nn.Linear(500,1)
    )
    
    criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss()
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
    
    for i in range (10000):
        y_pred = model(x1)
        loss = criterion(y_pred, y1)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
    
        if i%100 == 0:
            print(loss)

    print(model(torch.tensor([6], dtype=torch.float32)))
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Possible solutions:

- input normalization
- batch normalization
- decrease learning rate
- change MSELoss to L1Loss (more stable with large errors)
- change optimizer, e.g. use Adam
- etc

An example:

```
import torch

x1 = torch.arange(1,600, 1, dtype=torch.float32).view(-1, 1)
y1 = x1*x1

model = torch.nn.Sequential(
    torch.nn.BatchNorm1d(1, affine=False),
    torch.nn.Linear(1,500),
    torch.nn.BatchNorm1d(500),
    torch.nn.ReLU(),
    torch.nn.Linear(500,1)
)

criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=1e-6)

for i in range(10000):
    y_pred = model(x1)
    loss = criterion(y_pred, y1)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    if i%100 == 0:
        print(loss.item())

model.eval()
print(model(torch.tensor([[6]], dtype=torch.float32)))
```